# Block direct IP access with NGINX with site behind Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm trying to block direct IP access with NGINX.

I added the following block

```
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name "";
  return      444;
}
```

I have another server block

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name aaa.domain.com

    ...
}
```

The problem is that after adding the server block for refusing direct IP access, I can no longer access my website via aaa.domain.com

It seems the first server block is catching all requests.

Note, I'm using Cloudflare, and I wonder if it might be related? Perhaps NGINX detects the incoming request from Cloudflare as being of direct IP access and blocks it? If so, how could I solve this?

If it matters, the above server blocks are on different files located in sites-enabled dir.

Comment: I don't think it is cloud flare related ! also you are right the first block is blocking access as is the default_server, try using only the second block and adding a condition like this  `if ($host != "yourdomain.com") { return 444; }` into you server block

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794688/2579733

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare give the list of IP and ranges. You deny all and you accept traffic from these IPs, and it will work -> https://serverfault.com/questions/601339/how-do-i-deny-all-requests-not-from-cloudflare